# Why does the span also get aligned to top when I have vertical-align one anchor tag and one button having same class

Tags: html, css, button, alignment

I was expecting that span to not align
why the span tag is aligning to top even if i have not targeted it , I have just applied properties to .btn class elements

```css
.btns {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  line-height: 2em;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="btns">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn" id="ggl">button1</a>
  <button class="btn" id="fb">button2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't understand this questions. The only insight I can give you is that span are inline elements, thus they will always be displayed within the line they are placed with

Comment: when i align two buttons - button1 and button2 using vertical align then why the span element is also aligned, i havn't applied vertical align property to it

Comment: the span is not aligned, since it is a inline elements it is as height as its text, and thats why it gives the impression that it is vertically aligned when it's not

Answer (score 2):

Span elements are inline elements, so they take up only the space they need to display themselves. You can't apply height and any height-related css property. If you want those to work, make sure to use a block element (a div for example)

I would advise you to use a flex box to keep all those elements on the same line as in the example

More on flexbox here: [MDN Docs for Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox)

More on Inline element here: [MDN Docs for Inline content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Inline-level_content)

```css
.btns {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.lorem {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  line-height: 2em;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="btns">
  <div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn" id="ggl">button1</a>
  <button class="btn" id="fb">button2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: +3 for an answer that is completely irrelevant .. needs some Mod investigation